# fadeIn fadeOut if flag = true / false

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, flags

Im trying to fade a box in when `flag = true` or fadeOut when `flag = false`.
I fetch the ids out of n array.

Why is my flag allways true?

```
function setContentBox() {
    for (var i = 0; i < jArrayText.length; i++){
        var flag = true;

        if(!flag){
            document.getElementById(textWord[i]).onclick = function () {
                var activeClass = $(this).find('.comment-box');
                activeClass.fadeOut();
                flag = true;
            };
        }else if(flag){
            document.getElementById(textWord[i]).onclick = function () {
                var activeClass = $(this).find('.comment-box');
                activeClass.fadeIn();
                flag = false;
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question ? Does it not work ?

Comment: Why flag always true?

Comment: What is your actual end goal? The code above doesn't seem to do what I suspect you want, but without knowing what you want...

Comment: Off-topic. I'd  say `flag` is the worst possible name for flag variable. :) Flag that indicates what?..

Comment: My actual goal is that when im clicking on the id again that it is fadingOut again

Comment: @idh1337: Ok, I guessed right in my answer then. I gave you two options: One uses the same `flag` for all elements, the other uses a flag for *each* element (I suspect you want the second one).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:

```
var flag = true;
```

sets `flag` to `true` at the beginning of every loop iteration. You'd want to move it above the `for`.

But that code has other issues. I suspect this is what you're looking for:

```
function setContentBox() {
    // Set flag to true *once*
    var flag = true;
    for (var i = 0; i < jArrayText.length; i++){
        // Hook the click event
        document.getElementById(textWord[i]).onclick = function () {
            var activeClass = $(this).find('.comment-box');
            // Use and update the flag
            if (flag) {
                activeClass.fadeIn();
            } else {
                activeClass.fadeOut();
            }
            flag = !flag;
        };
    }
}
```

That uses the same `flag` for **all** elements. If you want a flag for each element, then:

```
function setContentBox() {
    for (var i = 0; i < jArrayText.length; i++){
        // Hook the click event
        document.getElementById(textWord[i]).onclick = function () {
            var activeClass = $(this).find('.comment-box');
            if (activeClass.data('flag')) {                 // `flag` exists and is true
                activeClass.fadeIn().data('flag', false);   // Set `flag` to `false`
            } else {                                        // `flag` is false or doesn't exist yet
                activeClass.fadeOut().data('flag', true);;  // Set `flag` to `true`
            }
        };
    }
}
```

*(Note I inverted the meaning of `flag` there.)*

**Or**, of course, [see Martijn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45856307/157247) if you don't actually need `flag` at all, just toggling.

Comment: This: `if (flag) {   activeClass.fadeIn(); } else {  activeClass.fadeOut();}` can be replaced by `activeClass.fadeToggle(flag)`

Comment: @Martijn: That [doesn't seem to be documented](http://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/).

Comment: I stand corrected. The toggle does that, the animated toggles apperantly don't, was too soon to reply. Next time, research before you speak kids, haha

Answer (score 1):

Checkout [`fadeToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadetoggle/):

```
function setContentBox() {
    for (var i = 0; i < jArrayText.length; i++){
        document.getElementById(textWord[i]).onclick = function () {
            $(this).find('.comment-box').fadeToggle();
        };
    }
}
```

And this might be done even easier:

```
$(".YourElements").on('click', function(e){
    $(this).find('.comment-box').fadeToggle();
});
```

Comment: I thought of `fadeToggle`, then....got all caught up in flags. Nice one.

Answer (score 0):

```
 function setContentBox() {
 var flag = true;
            for (var i = 0; i < jArrayText.length; i++){


                if(!flag){
                    document.getElementById(textWord[i]).onclick = function () {
                        var activeClass = $(this).find('.comment-box');
                        activeClass.fadeOut();
                        flag = true;
                    };
                }else if(flag){
                    document.getElementById(textWord[i]).onclick = function () {
                        var activeClass = $(this).find('.comment-box');
                        activeClass.fadeIn();
                        flag = false;
                    };

                }
            }
        }
```

try this

Comment: Why? What did you change? Why did you change it? Code dumps are not *useful* answers.

Comment: i change same as you just put var flag = true; out side the loop

Answer (score -1):

**Try this:**

1) fade in / fade out a comment box on click of some button provided a flag is true

```
 var flag = true; // if you need fade in and out effect
    function setContentBox() {
        for (var i = 0; i < jArrayText.length; i++){
                document.getElementById(textWord[i]).onclick = function () {
                    var activeClass = $(this).find('.comment-box');
            if(flag){
                    activeClass.fadeToggle(); // fades in if hidden, fades out if shown                
            }
                };       
    }
```

}

2) fade in / fade out a comment box on click of some button (if it is hidden fade in and if it is shown fade out) you do not need a flag in case if you want to achieve this

```
    function setContentBox() {
        for (var i = 0; i < jArrayText.length; i++){
                document.getElementById(textWord[i]).onclick = function () {
                    var activeClass = $(this).find('.comment-box');     
                    activeClass.fadeToggle(); // fades in of hidden, fades out if shown 
                };       
    }
}
```